# C# - how to notify user if to be inserted values to mysql is already there

Tags: c#, mysql

Is it possible in C# to alert user (with MessageBox) and `return;` if he's inserting same values to columns with unique constraint? I have unique in LastName, FirstName, and MiddleInitial.

```
String command = "INSERT IGNORE INTO studentstbl (LastName, FirstName, MiddleInitial, Address, Age, Birthday, Gender, Guardian, ContactNumber, Year, IsEnrolled) VALUES (@lastname, @firstname, @middleinitial, @address, @age, @birthday, @gender, @guardian, @contactnumber, @year, 0);";

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(command, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastnametxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstnametxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middleinitial", middleitxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addresstxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", agetxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthday", birthdaypicker.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gendercmb.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guardian", guardiantxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumber", contactnumtxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", yearcmb.Text);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    reset();
                    MessageBox.Show("Student successfully registered! You can now proceed to Payment to enroll student.");
                    conn.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: what about check for existence, before executing insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to run a query to check first, or take off the "IGNORE" from you query, so you can catch the error. If you take the "IGNORE" off, you can catch the more specific MySqlException and check the error number. 1062 means there was a unique key violation. The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html) has a full list of the error numbers. Something like this:

```
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    switch (ex.Number)
    {
        case 0:
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
            break;
        case 1045:
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
            break;
        case 1062:
            MessageBox.Show("Name already exists");
    }
}
finally
{
    //Since you've taken the ignore off you can run whatever you wanted to run here.
}
```

Comment: Just tried your code but nothing happens when I try to insert same values, no messagebox showing and nothing's happening. Why's that?

Comment: Did you make sure that you took the "IGNORE" out of the query? Because that basically tells it not throw an error.

Comment: Yes, I removed IGNORE but still no MessageBox showing.

Comment: Alright, give me a few minutes to set this up on my end.

Comment: I just found out it's not 1169 but 1062, I coded in mysql console

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the answer. Sorry about the misinformation.